# Neo4j store is not cleanly shut down; Recovering from inconsistent db state from interrupted batch insertion

Tags: database, neo4j

I was importing ttl ontologies to dbpedia following the blog post http://michaelbloggs.blogspot.de/2013/05/importing-ttl-turtle-ontologies-in-neo4j.html. The post uses BatchInserters to speed up the task. It mentions

Batch insertion is not transactional. If something goes wrong and you don't shutDown() your database properly, the database becomes inconsistent.

I had to interrupt one of the batch insertion tasks as it was taking time much longer than expected which left my database in an inconsistence state. I get the following message:

> db_name store is not cleanly shut down

How can I recover my database from this state? Also, for future purposes is there a way for committing after importing every file so that reverting back to the last state would be trivial. I thought of git, but I am not sure if it would help for a binary file like index.db.

Comment: As it says if you shutdown not cleanly you brick your database. Usually the importer is really fast, so perhaps share your configuration that you used. And try on a smaller dataaset first to verify that your config is correct.

Comment: Thanks, doing that. Will upload the configuration in a few hours when I am done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some cases where you cannot recover from unclean shutdowns when using the batch inserter api, please note that its package name `org.neo4j.unsafe.batchinsert` contains the word `unsafe` for a reason. The intention for batch inserter is to operate as fast as possible.

If you want to guarantee a clean shutdown you should use a try finally:

```
BatchInserter batch = BatchInserters.inserter(<dir>);
try {

} finally {
   batch.shutdown();
}
```

Another alternative for special cases is registering a JVM shutdown hook. See the following snippet as an example:

```
BatchInserter batch = BatchInserters.inserter(<dir>);

// do some operations potentially throwing exceptions

Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        batch.shutdown();
    }
});
```

Comment: I had the shutdown hook, as in the code. But the code took all the resources in the machine, and was thus killed.

I imported this data earlier in the virtuoso. Is there a way to migrate the virtuoso database into neo4j instead?

Or if two neo4j databases can be merged, then that can be an effective solution too. I can import all files separately and then merge these databases to each other.

Comment: From a gut feeling this sounds like a memory issue. Be sure to use enough memory on your JVM (-Xmx). If you're using index operations from batch inserter, make sure to call flush on the BatchInserterIndex  ( http://api.neo4j.org/current/org/neo4j/unsafe/batchinsert/BatchInserterIndex.html#flush() ). Never used virtuoso, so cannot say something about it. You might look at Talend ETL, it has a Neo4j connector and maybe one for virtuoso.